# Codeigniter : Cant load database in my library.

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

When I try to call

```
$this->load->database();
```

yields the following error `"Call to a member function database() on a non-object"

Autoloading the database doesnt help too...
when I try to autoload it. 
all calls to database like

```
$this->db->get('people');
```

it says get method is undefined...

 I have no clue what and where to start..
\
anyone ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to autoload.php in `application/config/autoload.php` and add this

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); // add database in array
```

Make sure your connection settings are fine in  `application/config/database.php`

Than in the library do it like this

```
Class MyLib
{
    function getPeople(){
        $CI =   &get_instance();
        $query  =   $CI->db->get('people');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Comment: :( .. still doesnt work ... I put the code in construct.. and added variable to set the $CI   .. still no luck...

Comment: if you autoload the database you dont have to do this. simple use `$CI->db->get('people');` and it will work

Comment: $CI =   &get_instance();  .... yikes looks like this code affects other code.....

Comment: @KebyangBlabla i have edited my answer and simplified it. Review it to get your problem solved. Also when you have model why use library

Comment: I just need to access some contents in my database in my library. 
 &get_instance(); I though it was a typo.. sorry.. Im migrating my code to model.... arghh.... sleepless nights.. woe woe...

Comment: This is outdated. I'm using CodeIgniter 4

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg this answer was given in 2013. If you are looking for latest answer go read the documentation https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Use extends CI_Model if not working try extends Model

```
class User_model extends CI_Model { 

     public function __construct() 
     {
           parent::__construct(); 
           $this->load->database();
     }
}
```

Comment: CodeIgnister 4 it's called just Model: `extends Model`

Answer (score 0):

You can load the database by two methods:

Method 1:Automatic Connecting

$autoload['libraries']=array('database');

Method 2: Manual Connecting

$this->load>database();

i hope above methods clear your confusion....

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a very common mistake. When you call `$this->load->database();` from `controller` or `model` it works because controllers and models are child of `CI_Controller` and `CI_Model` respectively. But when you are call them from Library which is not a child class of any basic `CI`class you cannot load database() or anything else using `$this->` key. you must use the help of  `&get_instance();` to load codeigniter instance and use that instance  instead of `$this`. Which suggests following Code:

```
$INST=&get_instance();//Store instance in a variable.
$INST->load->database();//If autoload not used.
$INST->db->get('people');//or Your desired database operation.
```

It is better to keep a field variable to hold the reference to `$INST`as you may need to access it in various functions.

Following Code will be more eligent:

```
 class MyLib{
     var $INST;
     public function __construct() 
     {
         $INST=&get_instance();//Store instance in a variable.
         $INST->load->database();//If autoload not used.
     }

     function getPeople(){
         $query  =  $INST->db->get('people');
         return $query->result();
     }
 }
```