# I would like to ask you about the CodeIgniter Model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I started the program with the following settings.

application/config/database.php

```
$db['default'] = array
(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'mysql',
    'database' => 'opentutorials',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'port' => '8080',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

application/controllers/topic.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Topic extends CI_Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->database(); // 1. database 를 핸들링 하기 위해서 해야 할 첫번째 작업 (데이터베이스 라이브러리 로드)
        $this->load->view('head');
        $this->load->view('main');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

    function get($id)
    {
        $this->load->view('head');
        $this->load->view('get', array('id'=>$id));
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
?>
```

I tried to verify that the database library was loaded correctly, but the following error occurred.
[image]

I do not know if I made the wrong setting. If someone knows about this issue, let me know the correct answer.

Comment: The error suggests that your database information (server/user/pass/database) does not match an existing database and user. Does that database exist? Does the user have access to it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900120/codeigniter-cant-load-database-in-my-library plese chk this

Comment: most of the time windows mysql password is empty. `'password' => 'mysql',` check settings first

Comment: are you sure the port number is 8080. The default mysql database port number is 3306.

Comment: There was a mistake. The localhost port number is 8080 and the mysql port number is 3307. So how can we solve this problem?

Comment: Make sure your file name of controller has the first letter uppercase only rest lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks your DB config is work. It is difficult to assume the exact issue without knowing the server configuration.

I am providing following checklist:

1. Check Database Username & password. Most of the case user is `root` and password is BLANK ie. ''.
2. Default MySQL port is `3306`, but you have given `8080`.
3. Check the database name
4. Check if there is any Database prefix? if available then user database name including prefix.

Here is an example of working DB config

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'dev_maindb',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```